# What does "SchemeError: pair is not callable" mean?

Tags: scheme

I'm running a Scheme program and getting an error when I run this code with s = (1 2 3 4 5), saying `SchemeError: pair is not callable: (1 2 3 4 5)`. I know what this error means in Python, but I'm not sure how it applies to Scheme.

This is my program.

```lisp
(define (ordered? s) 
    (define (helper val lastVal newS)
        (if (null? cdr(newS))
            (val)
            (if (<= lastVal car(newS))
                (helper #t car(newS) cdr(newS))
                (helper #f car(newS) cdr(newS))
            )
        )
    )
    (helper #t 0 s)
)
```

Comment: e.g., `cdr(newS)` is not a function call in lisps; instead use `(cdr newS)`, `(car newS)`. Also, look at some lisp code written by experienced lispers for style pointers. Prefer `kebab-case` to `camelCase`. Avoid scattering `)` closing parenths across multiple lines; parentheses are not braces.

Comment: `cdr(newS)` means 2 sexps, `cdr` and `(newS)`.  Probably _newS_ is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I was using the car and cdr procedures wrong, so I was getting extra parenthesis around my list.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).